# Why is my javascript window.opener.location.reload reloading a different URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, so I have a form, which allows a user to make a booking on an event as follows:

```
<h3>Booking Form</h3>
<p><form method="post" action="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=submitBooking" class="bookingForm">
<label for="role">Booking:</label>
<select name="role" id="role">
<option value="Player">Play</option>
<option value="Monster">Monster</option>
<option value="MIA">Unable to Attend</option>
<option value="Referee">Referee</option>
</select><br />
<div id="AttendeeName"><label for="bookingName">Attendee Name:</label><select name="bookingName" id="listedBookingName">
<option value="1">3rd spearman</option>
<option value="2">4th spearman</option>
</select></div>
<div id="CharacterName"><label for="characterName">Character Name:</label><select  name="CharacterName" id="listedCharacterName">
<option value="1">Jack Dawkins</option>
<option value="2">Reverand Blighty Shrewson</option>
<option value="3">Sydion</option>
**</select><button class="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.heroesandheroines.org/index.php?task=siteForm', '', 'width=500, height=500');"><span class="formButton">create a new character</span>**</button></div>
<div id="telephoneNumber"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number:</label>
<input required type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="0123456789" /></div>
<div id="emailAddress"><label for="email">E-mail Address:</label>
<input required type="email" id="email" name="email" value="madeup@email.com" /></div>
<div id="notes"><label for="notes">Notes:</label>
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="notes" /></textarea>
</div><input type="hidden" name="returnPage" value="http://heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events/124_tbc.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="dungeonid" value="124" />
<input type="submit" name="submit Booking" value="Submit Booking" />
&nbsp;<a href="">CANCEL</a></p>
</form>
```

The button `<button class="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.heroesandheroines.org/index.php?task=siteForm', '', 'width=500, height=500');">` fires open a new window, which allows a user to create  a a new character for use on the event.

The new window has the folowing javascript:

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload()
    }
</script>
```

Now, it's a work in progress, but what I WANT is for the child window to refresh the parent window, HOWEVER, the child window doesn't refresh the original content of the parent window (http://heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=bookingForm&eventID=124)... It loads http://heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=submitBooking which is the target of the form... How do I get the parent window to refresh its URL rather than the form submit URL?

Also, I'm quite confused as to WHY it's behaving like this... surely window.opener.location.reload SHOULD simply refresh the page from the request URI or something?

Comment: `action="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=submitBooking"` Your `form` is being submitted, therefore the `URL` is being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<button>` has a [`type` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), which defaults to `submit`.  IE when you click your button, as well as opening the new window, it's also submitting the form in the background, which is updating your URL.  Add in the `type` attribute to your button, and specify it as `button` - this will stop the form from submitting in the background:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.heroesandheroines.org/index.php?task=siteForm', '', 'width=500, height=500');">
```

Comment: As an addendum: this doesn't seem like great UX - if the user does some work in the form, then clicks the button, when that window closes, the page will reload and the user will lose whatever they've entered so far

Comment: Yeah, I'm just in the middle of it so it's just a work in progress, but that's a good point which I hadn't thought of! Basically, the user will create the new character using the popup, submit the form (triggering the 'refreshParent' function) and I then need to add that new character to the pull-down 'characterName', but I hadn't thought about the fact that this will then erase all the work that they have done in the form... Dammit! Thanks for the tip, and thanks for the solution which works perfectly! :)